# I am confused as to the Data type

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Hack Reactor prep-program problem, the problem is listed below.  My question is what is the data type of the customerData?  It appears to be an object, but each property is preceded by a name "Joe" and then a key-value pair.  I think of a JavaScript object as having properties with key-value pairs.

The problem:

Write a function called "greetCustomer".

Given a name, "greetCustomer" returns a greeting based on how many times that customer has visited the restaurant.  Please refer to the customerData object.

The greeting should be different, depending on the name on their reservation.

```
Case 1 - Unknown customer ( Name is not present in customerData ): 

var output = greetCustomer('Terrance');
console.log(output); // --> 'Welcome! Is this your first time?'

Case 2 - Customer who has visited only once ( 'visits' value is 1 ):

var output = greetCustomer('Joe');
console.log(output); // --> 'Welcome back, Joe! We're glad you liked us the first time!'

Case 3 - Repeat customer: ( 'visits' value is greater than 1 ):

var output = greetCustomer('Carol');
console.log(output); // --> 'Welcome back, Carol! So glad to see you again!'

Notes:
* Your function should not alter the customerData object to update the number of visits.
* Do not hardcode to the exact sample data. This is a BAD IDEA:


if (firstName === 'Joe') {
  // do something
}

Starter Code :
*/

var customerData = {
  'Joe': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Carol': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Howard': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Carrie': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';
  // your code here

  return greeting;
}
```

Comment: That's a JavaScript object which behaves a lot like a dictionary in other languages. If you ever want to know more, [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) has the answers: `console.log(typeof(customerData))`.

Comment: To be accurate, it's simply an object. JSON is a notation (that's what the 'N' is). It's a string representation of a JavaScript Object.

Comment: @tadman — http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Dancrumb Yeah, sorry, a little quick to jump in there. Adjusted veribage. JSON just on the mind lately.

Comment: Thank you to all for your input.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It is an object.

The syntax of an object literal is `{` and `}` containing a set of key: value pairs separated by commas.

The keys can be strings or identifiers (in this case they are strings), and the values can be any expression that resolves to a value (in this case: More object literals).

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an object that contains objects.

First object key is name, and the returned object key is visits.

```js
var customerData = {
  'Joe': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Carol': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Howard': {
    visits: 3
  },
  'Carrie': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';
  var customer = customerData[firstName]
  if (!customer) {
    greeting = 'Hello New Customer';
  } else {
    var visits = customer.visits;
    switch (visits) {
      case 0:
        greeting = 'Hello New Customer';
        break;
      case 1:
        greeting = 'Thanks For Coming Back';
        break;
      case 2:
      default:
        greeting = 'Thanks For Being A Regular';
        break;
    }
  }

  return greeting;
}

console.log(greetCustomer('Felix'))
console.log(greetCustomer('Joe'))
console.log(greetCustomer('Howard'))
```

Answer (score -2):

customerData looks to be of the form of JSON.

Some of the types of JSON structures are as follows:

```
{key: value}
{a: {a:b}}
{a : {[b,c,d]}}
```

There are ways to parse the JSON in the form that you want. JSON Serialization and Deserialization may help too.

Comment: I prefer to use it in my projects and just because a site says so, doesnt mean its true. You may call it Object, I may call it JSON.

In the end, both are representations of data.

Comment: Words have meaning. JSON and JavaScript are different things. My car has seats. My dining table has seats. That doesn't mean my car's driver's seat is a dining table.